# SonarQube incompatible with Gradle 7.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sonarqube

I'm running [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) Gradle Version 3.0 with `Gradle 6.7.1`, when I run `gradle sonarqube` I've got a Gradle FAILURE: :

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
```

App/build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

build.gradle :

```
buildscript {

    ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.0" // Added for SonarQube
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" // Added for SonarQube
        }
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

Comment: I&#39;m pretty sure this is not the reason for your builds failure. It is just a warning that a feature currently working will not work in an upcoming version of Gradle. This is pretty common when working with new versions of Gradle, because plugin authors need some time to adapt their plugins when features get deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATE] 26 Dec 2020**

I have tried using `gradle-6.7.1` and still SonarQube incompatible with Gradle 7.0, alternatively I use [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/) to get feedback on code. *By default Android can use [Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint)